# Second monitor flashes static when viewing Netflix in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, multiple-monitors, microsoft-edge, hdcp

NOTE: This happens in other HD-streaming apps, too, but it doesn't happen in the MS Edge browser.

I have two identical Samsung 27D850T monitors, running at 60Hz connected on DisplayPort and HDMI respectively.  This also happens when they are both on the DP ports (but I had some sleep-related powerup issues and it works better like this).

After a few seconds (up to a minute or so) the secondary monitor will flicker and flash with static. As soon as I stop the stream (having to return to the browse page) the flickering stops immediately.

This happens in Chrome and Firefox (latest).

One thing I've noticed is that while Chrome and Firefox show the image when dragging the browser from monitor to monitor, Edge doesn't.  It blanks out the image in the 'target' monitor until the whole browser has moved across.  This makes me think it's something to do with HDCP.

Any ideas what I can do about it?  Are there some Chrome flags anyone knows about that might help with this?  Can I disable HDCP or something?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on MS Edge. When I turned off hardware acceleration, the issue stopped immediately. It might be worth checking if hardware acceleration is *on* in your Chrome and Firefox settings and if its *off* for Edge.